# How to pass in 100 ids in one go when calling a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which takes `ANLSID` as a parameter. I have another table which consists of 100 `ANLSID`.

How do I write the loop/cursor or anything so that at one run the query runs for 100 `@ANLSID` so that I don't have to give the `@ANLSID` 100 times as an input?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on exact DBMS you're using.

Comment: No Need of loop or cursor, Instead you can return those IDs as CSV values, using stuff operator and this pertains to the MS SQL Server

Comment: Thanks Krishna.I am using MS SQL server.I have no idea abut stuff operator.Can you give an example?

Comment: You need to re-write the stored procedure so that it can (ideally) accept a table-valued parameter and uses set-based logic throughout. You can't just fix this from the calling side.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query correctly, you want to pass all the id's of a table in stored proc. You actually don't need to pass any id. You can simply loop through your table rows in stored proc itself.

Hope it help.